# Goaccess does not parse all the file

Tags: logging, nginx, goaccess

I have a nginx custom log file which is like :

`{ "timestamp": "2015-12-20T12:30:40+03:30", "remote_addr": "80.253.148.194", "remote_user": "-", "body_bytes_sent": "0", "request_time": "0.000", "status": "304", "request": "GET /repository/9/13350-000036.png HTTP/1.1", "request_method": "GET", "http_referrer": "http://domain.ltd/profile/category/1425", "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0" }
{ "timestamp": "2015-12-20T12:30:40+03:30", "remote_addr": "80.253.148.194", "remote_user": "-", "body_bytes_sent": "0", "request_time": "0.000", "status": "304", "request": "GET /repository/9/13349-000018.png HTTP/1.1", "request_method": "GET", "http_referrer": "http://domain.ltd/profile/category/1425", "http_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0" }
{ "timestamp": "2015-12-20T12:27:24+03:30", "remote_addr": "79.175.174.23", "remote_user": "-", "body_bytes_sent": "139008", "request_time": "0.298", "status": "206", "request": "GET /repository/9/56766da1202f7.mp4 HTTP/1.1", "request_method": "GET", "http_referrer": "-", "http_user_agent": "Lavf/56.4.101" }...`

it consists 3792061 rows.

i've setup the log format and it works fine , but after the job is done there's some data missing like there's no `/9/` files in the report.
[HERE](http://pastebin.com/raw/LADNtiJh) is my goaccess report.

and my command is :
`# goaccess -o json --static-file=.mp4 --static-file=.MP4 --ignore-panel=VISITORS --ignore-panel=REQUESTS --ignore-panel=NOT_FOUND --ignore-panel=HOSTS --ignore-panel=OS --ignore-panel=BROWSERS --ignore-panel=VISIT_TIMES --ignore-panel=VIRTUAL_HOSTS --ignore-panel=REFERRERS --ignore-panel=REFERRING_SITES --ignore-panel=KEYPHRASES --ignore-panel=GEO_LOCATION --ignore-panel=STATUS_CODES --sort-panel=REQUESTS_STATIC,BY_BW,DESC --debug-file debug.log --invalid-requests invalid.log -f ./access.json > data.json`

invalid requests file has 40 rows which is ignorable.

But afterwards i've split my files and find the rows with `/9/` in it `# cat access.json | fgrep '/9/' ./access.json > newlog.json`

i execute exactly the same command in goaccess for this log and i get [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/LbajuSS7) output which is fine.

Got stuck there, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only displays the top 366 items.

> each active window has a total of 366 items. Eventually this will be
>   customizable. These 366 items are all available by default in the CSV
>   and JSON exports, and as an expandable panel in the HTML report
>   (upper-right corner).

http://goaccess.io/man#notes